# Find the index of the second occurrence of a string inside a list

Tags: python, string

This is my list and code:

```
x=[["hi hello"], ["this is other"],["this"],["something"],["this"],["last element"]]
for line in x:
    y=x.index(line)
    #code
```

The first time it gets "this", it works properly, but for the second time, it gets the index of the first "this" only!

How can I find the second occurrence of a string inside a list?

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly? Seems like you are storing a single string in a list and that seems unnecessary

Comment: actually, i'm reading a file, and store in a list called x! i just gav simple example!!

Comment: Try checking out my answer I think I know what you are trying to do

Comment: No! its complicated! Anyhow i got the answer, thank you...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) here.

```
>>> x=[["hi hello"], ["this is other"],["this"],["something"],["this"],["last element"]]
>>> for index, line in enumerate(x):
        print index, line


0 ['hi hello']
1 ['this is other']
2 ['this']
3 ['something']
4 ['this']
5 ['last element']
```

Comment: Glad this helped you out. :)

Comment: ya...used your solution, and its working for me... thankx again!

Answer (score 4):

You can get the second easily enough by using [list slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation). In the example below, we find the index of the first occurance and then find the index of the first occurance in the sub-list that begins just after the first occurance.

```
x=[["hi hello"], ["this is other"],["this"],["something"],["this"],["last element"]]
for line in x:
    first=x.index(line)
    second=x[first+1:].index(line)
    #code
```

Bare in mind that using `list.index()` will return a `ValueError` if the object isn't in the list. Thus you may want some exception handling around your inner loop.

So the final code will look somewhat closer to this:

```
x=[["hi hello"], ["this is other"],["this"],["something"],["this"],["last element"]]
for line in x:
    print lines
    try:
        first=x.index(line)
        second=x[first+1:].index(line)
    except:
        first,second=-1,-1
    print first,second
    #code
```

Answer (score 1):

If getting the indices of the keyword is the only thing you need to do, then storing strings in a list is unnecessary (even if this was just an example you thought of!).

This function would print out each line and *all* the indices of the keyword (if any) that you give found per line in the file:

```
def getIndices(keyword):

    f = open('pathToYourFile', 'r')
    for line in f:

        wordList = line.split()
        buf = line.strip("\n") + ": "

        i = 0
        while i < len(wordList):
            if wordList[i] == keyword:
                buf += str(i) + " "
            i += 1

        print buf
```

This way you won't be limited to the keyword "this" and 1st/2nd occurrences.
For example, let's say your file looked like this:

```
hello this
this is cool
hello there
this this this
```

Then the function will work like this:

```
>>> getIndices("this")
hello this: 1 
this is cool: 0 
hello there: 
this this this: 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `index()` also takes a second argument where you can specify the start value.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.index

Here is the modified code:

```
x=[["hi hello"], ["this is other"],["this"],["something"],["this"],["last element"]]

y_list = []
for line in x:
    y=x.index(line)
    if y in y_list:
        y = x.index(line, y+1)
    y_list.append(y)
    print(y)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```